# Flutter animation for Draggable widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm trying to add animation to Draggable widget. The main goal is to slide back to initial position if widget was dropped or not accepted by drag target.
Could someone help me with simple code example or workaround(i need such entities as draggable object and target to drop it), or some different way to achieve my goal.

Tried physics and animatedpositioned but failed to make widget slide back to initial position after it was dropped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that I used animatedpositioned wrong. Here is the working example for draggable wrapped with animatedpositioned:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Flutter code sample for [AnimatedPositioned].

void main() => runApp(const AnimatedPositionedExampleApp());

class AnimatedPositionedExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const AnimatedPositionedExampleApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('AnimatedPositioned Sample')),
        body: const Center(
          child: AnimatedPositionedExample(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AnimatedPositionedExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnimatedPositionedExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<AnimatedPositionedExample> createState() =>
      _AnimatedPositionedExampleState();
}

class _AnimatedPositionedExampleState extends State<AnimatedPositionedExample> {
  bool selected = false;
  int animation_speed = 0;
  double initial_x = 50;
  double initial_y = 50;
  late double x = initial_x;
  late double y = initial_y;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 200,
      height: 350,
      child: Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: <Widget>[
          AnimatedPositioned(
            top: y,
            left: x,
            duration: Duration(seconds: animation_speed),
            curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {},
              child: Draggable<int>(
                key: const Key('mywidgetkey'),
                onDragStarted: () {},
                onDragUpdate: (details) => {
                  setState(() {
                    animation_speed = 0;
                    x = x + details.delta.dx;
                    y = y + details.delta.dy;
                  })
                },
                onDraggableCanceled: (velocity, offset) {
                  setState(() {
                    animation_speed = 2;
                    x = initial_x;
                    y = initial_y;
                  });
                },
                onDragEnd: (details) {},
                data: 10,
                feedback: Container(
                  color: Colors.deepOrange,
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  child: const Icon(Icons.directions_run),
                ),
                childWhenDragging: Container(
                  height: 100.0,
                  width: 100.0,
                  color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text('Child When Dragging'),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Container(
                  height: 100.0,
                  width: 100.0,
                  color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text('Draggable'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```